# Trouble comparing JSON (or custom PS) objects

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with object comparison.

I have an application which spits out JSON data. Each time I run my script, I will get the current values and import the stored values from the previous run (either from a .json or .xml file). At the end of the script, I will overwrite the stored values with the current values. The data looks like this:

Stored values:

```
id                  : 6549888
description         : Windows CPU via WMI
name                : Test
dataPoints          : {@{id=6314; dataSourceId=6549888; name=CPUBusyPercent; description=%
                  of Busy CPU; alertTransitionInterval=8; alertClearTransitionInterval=0; type=2; dataType=2;
                  maxDigits=4; postProcessorMethod=expression;
                  postProcessorParam=100-(PercentProcessorTime/100000); rawDataFieldName=; maxValue=; minValue=0;
                  userParam1=; userParam2=; userParam3=; alertForNoData=3; alertExpr=>= 50 60 70; alertSubject=CPU
                  alert on ##HOST##; alertBody=The host ##HOST## is in state ##LEVEL##. CPU is ##VALUE## percent
                  busy - it has been in this state since ##START##, or for ##DURATION##}}
```

Current values:

```
id                  : 6549888
description         : Windows CPU via WMI
name                : Test
dataPoints          : {@{id=6314; dataSourceId=6549888; name=CPUBusyPercent; description=%
                  of Busy CPU; alertTransitionInterval=8; alertClearTransitionInterval=0; type=2; dataType=2;
                  maxDigits=4; postProcessorMethod=expression;
                  postProcessorParam=100-(PercentProcessorTime/100000); rawDataFieldName=; maxValue=; minValue=0;
                  userParam1=; userParam2=; userParam3=; alertForNoData=3; alertExpr=>= 90 95 98; alertSubject=CPU
                  alert on ##HOST##; alertBody=The host ##HOST## is in state ##LEVEL##. CPU is ##VALUE## percent
                  busy - it has been in this state since ##START##, or for ##DURATION##}}
```

In this example, someone changed the alertExpr from "50 60 70" to "90 95 98" and I need to catch that (along with changes made to the rest of the properties).

When I run a foreach loop, I am not getting back any differences, but when I look at a single property, Powershell does report the difference. So the following returns nothing:

```
foreach ($dataSource in $currentDataSources) {
    foreach ($recordedDatasource in $previousDataSources) {
        If ($dataSource.id -eq $recordedDatasource.id) {
            Compare-Object $dataSource $recordedDatasource
        }
    }
}
```

But looking at the index 1034 (that's my test item) does show a difference:

```
Compare-Object $currentDataSources[1034].datapoints.alertexpr $previousDatasources[1034].datapoints.alertexpr
```

What is the best way to check each of the properties between my to sets of data?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you're looking for a recursive comparison, and I haven't found a great one yet.  Unless someone else has something, I've written one... I'll see if it's on point for your issue and whether I can share it.  Mine was focused on unordered nested hash tables.

Comment: So what show  when you print both of those? `$currentDataSources[1034].datapoints.alertexpr` and `$previousDatasources[1034].datapoints.alertexpr` to screen?

Comment: Simply add `.datapoints` to each object in `Compare-Object`? Also, you might want to index previousDataSources by id in order not to enumerate the entire collection each time.

Comment: @Matt I get >= 50 95 98 and >= 90 95 98.

Comment: @wOXXOm, it isn't just the datapoints that I need to monitor. If someone changes the name, or any other property, I need to catch it.

Comment: and what is the result of this `($currentDataSources[1034].datapoints.alertexpr).GetType.FullName`. System.String yes?

Comment: `What is the best way to check each of the properties between my to sets of data?` You are going to need to build your own comparison logic for something that complex.